# How do I run twilio in next.js 12 with typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, twilio

I'm getting the following error:

```
./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:15:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'net'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js
./node_modules/twilio/lib/base/RequestClient.js
./node_modules/twilio/lib/index.js
./pages/api/sendMessage.ts
./pages/api/queue/sms.ts
./pages/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

(also similar errors in the console for "tls" and "fs")

My /api/sendMessage.ts looks like this:

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const token = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

// METHOD 1
// import twilio from 'twilio';
// const client = twilio(accountSid, token);

// METHOD 2
// const client = require("twilio")(
//   accountSid,
//   token
// );

export type messageParams = {phone: string, message: string}

export default function sendMessage({ phone, message }: messageParams) {
  console.log("lets get going")

  client.messages.create({
    body: message,
    from: "+19124915149",
    to: phone,
  })
}
```

When METHOD 1 and METHOD 2 are commented out, I can run as expected. However, uncommenting either method causes the above error to be thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the `/pages/index` file?

Comment: Turns out that twilio only works on the backend -- the function that calls the twilio package needs to have the (req, res) parameters